# SRV record for subdomain: Do I also need a CNAME or A record for that same subdomain?

Tags: domain, subdomain, cname-record, srv-record

I have a service running on port xxxxx. I want to access that service through a subdomain (myspecialservice.mydomain.com). I know I need to create an SRV record that looks like _Service._Proto.myspecialservice TTL Class SRV Priority Weight xxxxx Target.

My question is, do I also need to add a CNAME or A/AAAA record for this subdomain? Or is the SRV record sufficient?

To be clear, my question is not about the target address.

Comment: What type of client(s) are using this service? (Does everything support `SRV`?)

Comment: The client programs are SRV aware. it's not a web browser or anything like that. I know those don't work with SRV (and aren't supposed to).

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Yes, you still need an A or CBAME (or Alias pseudo record).

The typical IP stack wont resolve an IP address from an SRV record (much like you still need ab A or CNAME when specifying an SMTP server for  mail despite the existence of an MX record)

Comment: This assumes that not all client software is `SRV`-aware, as I understand it?

Comment: No. From the question it can be assumed that the client understands SRV - otherwise there is no sense to the question at all. But even then, SRV defines that there is no IP there, but a name.that SRV points TO.

Comment: @TomTom The question also makes it clear that it's not asking about the target, so I guess that just makes this answer incorrect?

Comment: @davidgo If this is indeed meant to be about the SRV target, maybe phrase it as some "No, however the target name still needs an address record" deal, to match the question?

Comment: @tomtom the question says "I want to access that service through a subdomain (myspecialservice.mydomain.com)" which says theprogram is not relying on the SRV record for the lookup, otherwise the subdomain would not be necessary.

Comment: @davidgo The question says that they *want* to use a subdomain for this purpose (but does not elaborate on why, could be that it makes sense in terms of naming) and have defined the `SRV` record under that subdomain (makes sense, as that is what they said that they wanted). It was also clarified in a comment that all the client programs are `SRV`-aware.  I don't believe that your conclusion that client applications are not using `SRV` because a subdomain was used is accurate.

Answer (score 3):

It's unclear which subdomain you mean, so let's take an example with two servers providing a mysterious *service* on TCP port 12765 with the same *priority* but a bit different weight.

```
_service._tcp.special.example.com. IN SRV 0 5 12765 provider1.example.com.
_service._tcp.special.example.com. IN SRV 0 7 12765 provider2.example.com.
```

Here:

- You **don't** need an `A` record for:

  - `_service._tcp.special.example.com.`
  - `_tcp.special.example.com.`
  - `special.example.com.`
- You **need** `A` records for:

  - `provider1.example.com.`
  - `provider2.example.com.`

(Avoid using `CNAME` records for simplicity & until you have strong knowledge on how DNS works.)